# Can other servlets access cdi beans in jsf application?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jsf

I have a problem that probably originates from my poor understanding of the jsf and faces servlet concept... I have finally gotten my jsf application to work on google app engine. It's taken a lot of time and some workarounds but it's up and running :) Now I want to use data from the application for an android app. No problem I thought, but of course there is... I thought I just could put an extra servlet inside the jsf application and access the same cdi beans I use for the web page. Apparently it's not that easy. When I try to inject the beans into the extra servlet they are null. When I created an extra Faces context for my servlet it actually worked! But only in the test environment... When I deployed to app engine that workaround didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you got an EAR file with an EJB and a WAR module? And does the WAR module classpath contain the jar file of the EJB module?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the CDI beans via the BeanManager. You can inject it as a resource. Then you can get the bean instances from the BeanManager. These beans are very simple, they just gives back a value to see their types.

The CDI bean:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@Named( value = "myCDIBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class MyCDIBean implements Serializable
{
  private String value = "named";

  public MyCDIBean() {}

  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue( String value_ )
  {
    value = value_;
  }
}
```

The JSF managed bean:

```
package x;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean( value = "myJSFManagedBean" )
@SessionScoped
public class MyJSFManagedBean implements Serializable
{
  private String value = "managed";

  public MyJSFManagedBean() {}

  public String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue( String value_ )
  {
    value = value_;
  }
}
```

The servlet:

```
package x;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Bean;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager;

@WebServlet( urlPatterns ={"/MyServlet"} )
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet
{
  @Resource
  BeanManager beanManager;

  public static <T> T getBeanInstance( BeanManager bm_, Class<T> class_ )
  {
    Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) bm_.getBeans( class_ ).iterator().next();
    CreationalContext<T> ctx = bm_.createCreationalContext( bean );
    T object = (T) bm_.getReference(bean, class_, ctx);
    return object;
  }

  protected void processRequest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    throws ServletException, IOException
  {  
    response.setContentType( "text/html;charset=UTF-8" );
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter())
    {
      out.println( "<!DOCTYPE html>" );
      out.println( "<html>" );
      out.println( "<head>" );
      out.println( "<title>Servlet NewServlet</title>" );      
      out.println( "</head>" );
      out.println( "<body>" );
      out.println( "<h1>Servlet MyServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>" );
      MyCDIBean named = getBeanInstance( beanManager, MyCDIBean.class );
      out.println( "<p>named bean value: <b>" + named.getValue() + "</b></p>" );
      MyJSFManagedBean managed = getBeanInstance( beanManager, MyJSFManagedBean.class );
      out.println( "<p>managed bean value: <b>" + managed.getValue() + "</b></p>" );
      out.println( "</body>" );
      out.println( "</html>" );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I've learnt a lot, even though it didn't solve my problem. I couldnt inject or lookup the bean manager in any way... Problem solved though! When I realized that every bean I needed was requestscoped, a simple Bean bean = new Bean() was enough. Feel a little embarrased that I made everything a lot more complicated than it was...

Comment: you are welcome! it is worth to see BalusC home page : https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz#block_24059 I hope you you don't mind I recommend it, dear @BalusC :)

Comment: Never instantiate an enterprise bean manually, because its resources wont be initialized (it makes the container). always inject beans with the @EJB/@Inject annotations. in this case the bean with a container managed life cycle will be initialized before the business method get called